# How to formally relate the Parry Markov chain to a uniformly chosen bi-infinite path

Tags: pr.probability

I tried reformulating the comment after Proposition 10 in [here](http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Irene.Marcovici/Publications/Mairesse_Marcovici_IJFCS2017.pdf) as follows:

Let G be an aperiodic irreducible graph with adjacency matrix $A \in \mathcal{M}_d(\{0,1\})$ and associated Parry matrix $P$.

**Theorem 1**

The Markov chain $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ over $G$ with transition matrix $P$ chooses its overall path uniformly.

**Proof**
See the comment right after the proof of Proposition 10 in [here](http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Irene.Marcovici/Publications/Mairesse_Marcovici_IJFCS2017.pdf)

Is this statement correct?

My supervisor told me it is not correct, because all paths have probability 0. I argued nevertheless that the bi-infinite paths resulting from the Parry Markov chain are uniformly chosen.

At first I thought my supervisor's comment was rather silly. But now I realise a potential problem.
What does it mean to choose a bi-infinite path uniformly? How do we define this? I guess I did not realise these issues until now.

Perhaps the terminology I use is too informal. It may be necessary to present the theorem in a different way.

We could have a Lemma as follows:

**Lemma 1**

Consider the Markov chain $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ over $G$ with transition matrix $P$. Then $P(X_0=x_0, ... , X_k = x_k)$ is equal to the limiting fraction of 2n+k-step paths with $x_0...x_k$ in the middle, in the limit $n$ towards infinity.

**Proof**
See the comment right after the proof of Proposition 10 in [here](http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Irene.Marcovici/Publications/Mairesse_Marcovici_IJFCS2017.pdf)

This Lemma I know to be true. But how can derive a nicer statement, like I tried in Theorem 1, in a formal way?